# Extracting XML values from two nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to extract the value in the moduleId attibute and the value from the Field node.  For example, in this first node I want to extract the `447` in the moduleId and the `124694` from the Field node.  I have the XML loaded in an XDocument.  The end result will be a Tuple where the first item is the value from the moduleId attribute and the second item is the value from the Field node.  Is there a way I can do this using one XLinq statement?

As a bonus...I only want to do it for nodes where the guid = "07a188d3-3f8c-4832-8118-f3353cdd1b73".  This part I can probably figure out if someone can tell me how to extract information from two nodes, but a bonus would be to add the WHERE clause in there for me :)

```
<Records>
    <Record moduleId="447">
        <Field guid="07a188d3-3f8c-4832-8118-f3353cdd1b73">124694</Field>           
    </Record>   
    <Record moduleId="447">
            <Field guid="07a188d3-3f8c-4832-8118-f3353cdd1b73">124699</Field>    
    </Record>
<Records>
```

I have gotten as far as extracting the Field value using this...

```
IEnumerable<string> c = from p in sourceDocument.Descendants("Field")
                        where p.Attribute("guid").Value == "07a188d3-3f8c-4832-8118-f3353cdd1b73"
                        select p.Value;
```

But I have no idea how to get information from both the Record node and the Field node.

Comment: Can you update your post with valid XML? You have multiple root elements here.

Comment: Consider editing your XML to properly close the `<Records>` element...the end tag is missing a `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var r = doc.Descendants("Record")
    .Where(n => n.Element("Field").Attribute("guid").Value == "07a188d3-3f8c-4832-8118-f3353cdd1b73")
    .Select(n => new { ModuleId = n.Attribute("moduleId").Value, Field = n.Element("Field").Value });

var a = r.ToArray();
```

Comment: That did it...seems so easy now that I see it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses **LINQ Query Syntax:**

```cs
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var query =
    from el in document.Root.Elements("Record")
    where (string)el.Element("Field").Attribute("guid") ==
        "07a188d3-3f8c-4832-8118-f3353cdd1b73"
    select new
    {
        ModuleId = (string)el.Attribute("moduleId"),
        Field = (string)el.Element("Field")
    };

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine
        ("ModuleId:[{0}]\nField:[{1}]\n--",
             item.ModuleId,
             item.Field);
}
```